# Multiple inheritance C++, how does the casting work?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I've been reading a book of computational geometry. In such book there's an introduction part where how to implement a basic Vertex data structure. The route followed by the book is the following.

It firstly explains how to implement a List data structure, and specifically the node interface is as follows

```
class Node {
public:
    Node();
    Node* getNext();
    Node* getPrev();
    void setNext(Node *x);
    void setPrev(Node *x);
    Node* insert(Node *x);
    Node* remove();
    void splice(Node *x);
private:
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
};
```

Then a Point class is implemented, with the following interface

```
class Point2D {
public:
    Point2D();
    Point2D(double x, double y);
    Point2D(const Point2D& p);
    void setX(double x);
    void setY(double y);
    double getX();
    double getX() const;
    double getY();
    double getY() const;
    Point2D operator+(Point2D& p);
    Point2D operator-(Point2D& q);
    Point2D operator-();
    Point2D& operator=(const Point2D& p);
    bool operator==(Point2D& p);
    bool operator!=(Point2D& p);
    bool operator>(Point2D &p);
    bool operator>=(Point2D &p);
    bool operator<(Point2D &p);
    bool operator<=(Point2D &p);
    friend Point2D operator*(double c, Point2D p);
    double getDistance(Point2D& q);
    double getLength();
    int orientation(Point2D p, Point2D q);
    int classify(Point2D p, Point2D q);
private:
    double x;
    double y;
};
```

And at last we have the vertex class

```
class Vertex : public Node, public Point2D {
public:
    Vertex(double x, double y);
    Vertex(Point2D x);
    Vertex *cw();
    Vertex *ccw();
    Vertex *neighbour(int direction);
    Point2D getPoint();
    Vertex *insert(Vertex *v);
    Vertex *remove(Vertex *v);
    void splice(Vertex *v);
    friend class Polygon;
};
```

Let's specifically to the methods

```
Point2D Vertex::getPoint() {
 return *((Point2D*)this);
}

Vertex *Vertex::insert(Vertex *v) {
 return (Vertex*)(Node::insert(v));
}
```

As you can see there's some casting involved. Now if I had single inheritance I know that all the data members would be like "stacked", and the casting would consist in computing an offset from the base address given by the base class.

Like:

```
class A {
 public: int a;
};

class B : public A {
 public: int b;
};
```

And somewhere

```
B b;
A a = *(A*)&b;
```

In this case I would say that, `b` has a base address (let's name such address `b_addr`, the casting to A (is not actually a casting, but anyway... maybe you've got my point) would involve to "consider" from `b_addr` to `b_addr + 4`. However I'm not sure how it would work this calculation in case of multiple inheritance. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: The objects are still stacked. When you cast, the compiler knows the relative placement of the particular base class and offsets `this` to it.

Comment: Is there instead something to know in the opposite case? when you cast from a base object to a derivate one?

Comment: No, there is nothing else to know. If object `A` is "stacked" `x` bytes from object `B`, then casting from `A` to `B` involves adding `x` bytes to the address, and `B` to `A` involves subtracting `x` bytes from the address.

Comment: Let's say you have `C : A, B`, where A is @ 0 and B is @ 8. The compiler knows how to add and subtract the offset of B when casting to and from B*, respectively.

Comment: `private` data are not inherited. you may meant `protected`

Comment: @Raindrop Those were a motivational examples, which purpose were to make the formulation of my question easier.

Comment: Clarifying above comment: `private` data is inaccessible to the inheritor, but it is still present.

Comment: By the way, in `getPoint`, `return *this;` would have worked just as well. The explicit cast is unnecessary. It's not clear why `Vertex` even provides this method - after all, `Vertex` is-a `Point2D`, an instance of `Vertex` can be used anywhere a `Point2D` is required.

Comment: And again, the code is mostly "copied-and-pasted". I'm not saying is the best code I've seen in my life.

Comment: Let compiler writers worry about these minute details.

Answer (score 0):

In case of single inheritance :

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B : A { int b; };
struct C : B { int c; }; 
C c;
```

Here `c`, `(B&)c` and `(A&)c` have the same address; there is no offset to add or substract from casting from one to any other struct of the hierarchy.

In case of multiple inheritance :

```
struct A { int a; };
struct B { int b; };
struct C : A,B { int c; }; 
C c;
```

Here `c` and `(A&)c` have the same address, however address of `(B&)c` is offsetted by `sizeof(A)` from address of `c`. Also, `(char*)&c.c == (char*)&c + sizeof(A) + sizeof(B)`.

Comment: last equality is not true unless casted to char*